# Date and WiFi password resets after battery dies

Tags: macbook-pro

Weird thing has started happening, basiaclly when your lid is closed and the battery dies, normally your MacBook should "hibernate" itself, yet what started happening on mine is that it completely shuts down. After restarting, the WiFi password is forgotten and date/time are resetted to detaults (year 2000).

Can it be that the PRAM battery already died on a Mid 2010 MBP i7?

Best Regards,
Oskar

Answer (score 1):

Yes, IMHO, that's the symptoms of a dead PRAM battery. You should simply change it, I don't think it cost a lot. But, you are right, that's indeed a rapid death...

Comment: Yeah, sounds like old school cmos problems.